# Dynamically change background image of each user in laravel blade template

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

i have different type of users in my application and each user have differerent type of background image for their wall like facebook but here i am confused ho to chang each user background image dynamically as their images name are coming from database and background image class is defined in css file . any solution will be highly appreciated as i am new to laravel and php . thnks

Comment: remove your backround-image:url() from css filefile and add it in your html tag in style attribute so you can put dynamic url in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as for laravel blade template engine the code will be like this

```
    @if(isset($data->coverphoto))
     <img src="{{asset('$data->coverphoto')}}"  title=""  />
    @elseif(empty($data->coverphoto) || $data->coverphoto == null)
     <img src="asset('placeholder.jpg')"  title=""  />
    @endif
```

first we will check if the data is existing or not then we will place image as a img tag another option is that we will use class like

```
.coverphoto{ 
background-image: url('<?= (isset($data->coverphoto))?asset('images/') . $data->coverphoto: asset('images/placeholder.jpg') ?>');
         }

<div class="coverphoto"> </div>
```